# ASP NET MVC com JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Fiz uma requisição ajax, mas a mesma não chama o controller, quando debugo o javascript nunca cai em success e pelo console aparece Erro no processamento de XML.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Cadastro(Pedido pedido)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var appPedido = new PedidoAplicacao();
    appPedido.Salvar(pedido);
    return Json(new { Resultado = "Sucesso" });
   }
 return Json(new { Resultado = pedido }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

View onde chamo a função do js:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <a href="#" id="SalvarPedido">Enviar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```
 function SalvarPedido() {


    var valor =  $('#Valor').val();
    var cadastro =  $('#Data').val();

    var url = "/Pedido/Cadastro";


    $.ajax({

        url: '/Pedidos/Cadastro' ,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { Id: 0, Data: cadastro, Valor: valor },            
        success: function (data) {
                alert('Ok');  
        }

    })
```

Ele nao chega a ir para o controller. Segue a imagem do console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do erro gerado na imagem acima:

> Erro no processamento de XML: nenhum elemento encontrado Posição:     http://localhost:52305/ddc764bf50734262b0fe681dedc10612/browserLinkSignalR/abort?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAA1b%2FiWAupl0K5akccJ4%2BqxQAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAAD4u4YF6%2BWCLuvA6%2BJMMZgapC3Z%2FT9%2B83WkoA7Flqi%2BgAAAAAOgAA

Comment: Qual é **exatamente** o erro? E onde ele ocorre? No console do browser ou no Visual Studio?

Comment: No console do browser

Comment: E a primeira pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei o print do erro na descrição.

Comment: Copia o texto do print e cola em formato de texto na pergunta, as imagens aqui na empresa são bloqueadas, não consigo ver.

Comment: Erro no processamento de XML: nenhum elemento encontrado
Posição: http://localhost:52305/ddc764bf50734262b0fe681dedc10612/browserLinkSignalR/abort?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAA1b%2FiWAupl0K5akccJ4%2BqxQAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAAD4u4YF6%2BWCLuvA6%2BJMMZgapC3Z%2FT9%2B83WkoA7Flqi%2BgAAAAAOgAA

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa serializar seu objeto JavaScript para JSON:

```
function SalvarPedido() {    

    var valor =  $('#Valor').val();
    var cadastro =  $('#Data').val();   

    var data = { Id: 0, Data: cadastro, Valor: valor };    
    var dadoSerializado = JSON.stringify(data);

     $.ajax({

          url: '/Pedidos/Cadastro',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          data: dadoSerializado,            
          success: function (data) {
                        alert('Ok');  
          }
     })
}
```